# How to pipe text from command line to the clipboard

Tags: linux, windows, macos, command-line, clipboard

I'd like to do something like

```
dir *.* > clipboard
```

ie. get to get the standard output of a command line program copied to the clipboard. Can this be done on a standard XP machine without additional programs?

Comment: Just for the archives: the Mac OS X equivalents are called `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/231023/windows-script-to-copy-some-text-to-the-clipboard/231032#231032     mentions http://www.petri.co.il/software/clip.zip  which is apparently on windows server 2003 or the 2003 resource kit maybe. But there it is for download

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't believe so - Vista (or NT4) introduced the `clip` tool, which would do your command as `dir | clip` - but there's nothing on XP. If you're willing to use 3rd party applications, though, there's [this](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Clipboard/DOE-CB.shtml), which works as above, except is called `cb`, not clip.

Comment: as a historical note, Arjan's link to the MS support note references NT4.  but you're probably right that consumer versions of Windows didn't include clip.exe before Vista.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. Never really get a chance to mess around on business machines! :(

Comment: if it's any consolation, i completely missed out on all the fun of Windows NT 3.51.  and i wasn't a fan of NT at all until i got to play with 2000 for a while.

Answer (score 21):

For Windows and non-Windows, [this post](http://mepem.com/pemtech/2010/01/21/pipe-to-clipboard-clip-xclip-pbcopy/) (dead link) used to say:

> On Windows Vista or later, try: `echo hello | clip`
>
> On Linux, try: `echo hello | xclip`
>
> On Mac OS X, try: `echo hello | pbcopy`
>
> For example, you might do `(cat myFile.txt | xclip)`.  This would basically allow you to edit the clipboard directly.

(I came here via Google looking for the Mac equivalent of `xclip`)

Similarly for contents of files (as you don't `cat` on windows):

> ```
> type filename | clip  % OR clip < filename   %windows
> cat filename | xclip  # OR xclip < filename  # X11 / Unix / Linux
> cat filename | pbcopy # OR pbcopy < filename # MacOS X
> ```

Comment: The link above is now throwing a 500.  For those of you unfamiliar with `pbcopy`, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't paste: you need to type (or alias to something shorter) `pbpaste`.

Comment: In WSL, you can access the `clip` of Windows by writing `clip.exe`.

Answer (score 6):

There's no standard way, but you can apparently use `clip.exe` which came with the Windows Server 2003 resource kit . [Source](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/copy-dos-command-line-output-clipboard-clip-exe/2506/)

The problem now becomes getting hold of a legal copy of this.

Comment: I wonder how legal that is. What sort of licensing do MS put their small cli tools under, I wonder?

Comment: It was also available in the NT 4 and Server 2000 Resource kit if you have either of those available to you. It does not seem to be available in the now free-to-download subset of the 2000 RK tools.

Answer (score 6):

I looked into this for myself earlier today.  Below is something helpful to those wanting to insert and retrieve information from the clipboard in a linux distribution.  Below that is something that could prove helpful for those with windows.

### Linux

> By default, xclip uses the "primary" clipboard, which is what you have copied with your mouse. To get it to use the manual copy clipboard, use xclip -sel clip
>   instead.

comment #3 here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=413786

### Windows

The functionality is available in Active Perl distribution also, which is what I wound up using on the windows box in this exercise; The windows clip.exe didn't appear to allow for reading the data from the clipboard (only writing into clipboard).

http://www.xav.com/perl/site/lib/Win32/Clipboard.html

Comment: Since you've mentioned perl, I would like to add that ruby and python provide similar library too.

Answer (score 2):

Windows users can get `gclip.exe` as part of a [big bundle of tools](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), which allows you to do just this.

Answer (score 1):

In [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx), it can be done like this:

```
dir *.* | clip
```

Comment: As an aside: see "Clip.exe Not Compatible with Notepad" at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172596

Comment: That link isn't relevant to PowerShell.  I've tested it and everything works fine with Notepad.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on XP, IF a Server 2003 clip.exe is in you path. Also works in a standard CMD prompt

Comment: clip is just an external tool so it'll work in any consoles, not only powershell

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows Vista and later DOS has a built in [clip command](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091110-00/?p=16093):

```
CLIP

Description:
    Redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard.
    This text output can then be pasted into other programs.

Parameter List:
    /?                  Displays this help message.

Examples:
    DIR | CLIP          Places a copy of the current directory
                        listing into the Windows clipboard.

    CLIP < README.TXT   Places a copy of the text from readme.txt
                        on to the Windows clipboard.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using cygwin on Windows (e.g. git for windows).
You better dump the content into a temp file,
then 'unix2dos' the temp file before really pipe to 'clip'

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. `clip` does not exist on Windows XP.