# Doskey for compound command

Tags: windows, command-line

Doskey works in modern versions of Windows for setting aliases for single commands, e.g. `doskey foo=bar`.

There's a slight problem trying to use it for compound commands like `doskey foo=bar & baz` since this gets interpreted as `(doskey foo=bar) & baz`. The obvious fix would be to add explicit parentheses, `doskey foo=(bar & baz)` but for some reason this doesn't work, and `doskey foo="bar & baz"` doesn't work either.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Escape the ampersand.

```
foo=bar ^& baz
```

Answer (score 22):

Use `$T` to separate commands:

```
doskey foo=bar $T baz
```

```
doskey cpdel=copy $1 $2 $T del $1
```

from `doskey /?`:

```
$T     Command separator.  Allows multiple commands in a macro.
```

Answer (score 11):

to add to the previous answers, you can also do this:

mybatfile.cmd

```
    doskey /macrofile=aliases.txt
```

aliases.txt

```
    foo=bar & baz
    cpdel=copy $1 $2 $T del $1
    cc=echo|set /p=$*|clip
```

note that in the macrofile, there is no need to escape pipe/ampersand and you can define multiple aliases in one call.

Answer (score 10):

To (somewhat) add on to [Dennis Williamson's answer](https://superuser.com/a/247549/350130), you can also escape the pipe character in order to pipe commands! For example, I wanted a command that copies stuff to the clipboard. Due to the way `COPY` will interpret it, you need to do [a goofy looking command](https://superuser.com/a/603232) for it to actually copy the text you specify without it being followed by a newline.

In order to define a macro for copying to the clipboard, you can escape the pipe with `^`:

```
doskey cc=echo^|set /p=$*^|clip
```

Upon execution of the command `cc hey`, you will now have `hey` copied to the clipboard!

Comment: I was also wondering how to prevent the copy of the newline character! Thanks.