# How to use && within a doskey?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I know I can run two commands back-to-back in the command line:

```
git add -u && git commit --amend --no-edit
```

I also have aliases setup using `doskey`

```
doskey a=git add $*
```

But how can I combine multiple commands in a single `doskey` alias?

```
doskey amend=git add -u && git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This fails by setting the `doskey` to the first command `doskey amend=git add -u` and then proceeds to immediately execute `git commit --amend --no-edit` at runtime instead of saving the composite command to the `doskey` alias.

I also tried quoting the whole thing:

```
doskey amend="git add -u && git commit --amend --no-edit"
```

But this fails too because it interprets the quotes literally:

> '"git add -u && git commit --amend --no-edit"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doskey for compound command](https://superuser.com/questions/247548/doskey-for-compound-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `&&` denotes the end of the `doskey` command and the second `git` command is executed in-line after it.

I have tried other syntax combinations, but none of them allows `&&` to be parsed after the `doskey` expansion, apart from:

```
doskey amend=cmd /c "git add -u && git commit --amend --no-edit"
```

This launches a new shell, which is inefficient. A better solution might be to put both commands into a batch file (eg `amend.cmd`) and assign the macro to this:

```
doskey amend=amend.cmd
```

Comment: Escape & characters using ^ as follows:

`DOSKEY amend=git add -u ^&^& git commit --amend --no-edit`

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528395/2047385

Answer (score 12):

This was the first result in the google but I found other similar question with nice answers.

1- escape the ampersand character `doskey foo=bar ^& baz`

2- use doskey's own command seperator `doskey foo=bar $T baz`

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/247548/doskey-for-compound-command)

This is cleaner and does not open extra command windows.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the one currently selected as correct has multiple issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain commands within an individual DOSKEY, using as Ali mentions using the `$T` or `^&` separators, however you cannot then chain the doskey command in your terminal. An example is in order

**This works**

```
doskey ls=dir $T echo YAY A FOLDER
```

See the output:

```
C:\tmp>ls
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-1234

 Directory of C:\tmp

23/07/2020  18:02    <DIR>          .
23/07/2020  18:02    <DIR>          ..
C:\tmp>YAY A FOLDER
C:\tmp>
```

**This doesn't**

```
C:\tmp>ls && echo YAY ANOTHER ECHO!!
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-1234

 Directory of C:\tmp

23/07/2020  18:02    <DIR>          .
23/07/2020  18:02    <DIR>          ..
C:\tmp>YAY A FOLDER
C:\tmp>
```

*BOO* there's no `YAY ANOTHER ECHO!!`

***A better solution***

Use batch files in a folder and set your PATH

1. Put `dir && echo YAY A FOLDER` in a file `C:\batch\ls.bat`
2. Set `path=%PATH%;C:\batch`
3. Run `ls && echo YAY ANOTHER ECHO!!`
4. Admire the lovely output

_

```
C:\tmp>ls && echo YAY ANOTHER ECHO!!
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-1234

 Directory of C:\tmp

23/07/2020  18:02    <DIR>          .
23/07/2020  18:02    <DIR>          ..
YAY A FOLDER
YAY ANOTHER ECHO!!

C:\tmp>
```

***PS** - for step 2 above better to permanently set your PATH environment variable.*

Answer (score 1):

Escape & characters using ^ as follows:

`DOSKEY amend=git add -u ^&^& git commit --amend --no-edit`

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528395/2047385