# Registry command for context menu item to copy folder name

Tags: windows, windows-registry, cmd.exe, clipboard, regedit

I often need to quickly copy the name of a folder in Windows 7, and so am trying to create an equivalent to the `Copy as path` item that appears in Extended context menus (i.e. when doing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>) that will copy only the name of the selected folder to the clipboard.

I've created the Registry key at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Copy folder name\command
```

...where all of my similar context-menu additions for folders are, and it can be seen here:

[image]

However, I've so far been unable to get the code that needs to be executed by the key working as it should. I've come across [this solution to grab the current folder of a directory](https://superuser.com/a/160712/323079), and [this one to pipe the directory name to the clipboard](https://superuser.com/a/231032/323079), and put them together to get the following:

```
for %* in (.) do set FolderName=%~nx* && echo %FolderName%| clip
```

**This code works exactly as expected in the command line.**

Prepending `cmd /c` to it, which is necessary to run a CMD instance from the Registry, gives the following:

```
cmd /c for %* in (.) do set FolderName=%~nx* && echo %FolderName%| clip
```

[image]

However, placing this in the value data of the `Default` string value in the `\Copy folder name\command` key, and then right-clicking a folder and clicking on *Copy folder name* fails to work.

Wrapping it in quotes also does nothing:

```
cmd /c "for %* in (.) do set FolderName=%~nx* && echo %FolderName%| clip"
```

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Escaping the pipe does nothing unfortunately, neither does getting rid of the last or first quote.

Comment: How about `cmd /V:ON /c "for %* in (.) do set FolderName=%~nx* && echo !FolderName!|clip"`

Comment: If it works from a BAT file you can call that from your context entry like: `"C:\\folderToClip.bat \"%1\"`

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yeah, I'd already tried enabling and disabling both Delayed Variable Expansion and Command Extensions, no such luck either way. I also used tried using `/k` instead of `/c` in the hope that the command window would remain open for debugging purposes, and ditto for `pause` - no such luck.

Comment: @HackSlash It's a last resort, but I'd really rather get such a short command done without any external dependencies.

Comment: Okay, I assume you tried `"FolderName=%~nx*"` quoting the variable that way too... i.e. `cmd /V:ON /c "for %* in (.) do set "FolderName=%~nx*" && echo !FolderName!|clip"`? I noticed this way trims off the trailing white space too.