# copy an & to the clipboard using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, clipboard

I have the following batch file script that I trying to run that will fetch my password to my clipboard.
I have tried multiple different methods but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
set "passwd=p455code&"
echo %passwd%|clip
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
C:\aliases>set "passwd=p455code&"

| was unexpected at this time.
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Forget using a variable for this, you don't need one.

The following 1 liner works:

```
echo|set/p="p455code&"|clip
```

Source: [Windows script to copy some text to the clipboard?](https://superuser.com/a/231032/337631), answer by [barlop](https://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the operator `&` without `^`escaping and send this "expected output" to pipe direct to `clip` command, and because the cmd.exe is interpreting as `run command & | command` you get the error:

> | was unexpected at this time.

Also, instead of expanding the value/strings saved in the variable to copy to the clipboard, use a listing of it and capture the value in a `for /f` loop:

```bat
set "_pwd=p455code^&"
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^= %i in ('set _pwd')do echo\%i|clip
```

---

- Invoking powershell in cmd:

```bat
powershell -nop -c "'p455code&'|clip"
```

- In PowerShell

```bat
'p455code&'|clip
```

---

- Some further reading:

  - **[Echo on | off](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
  - **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
  - **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
  - **[Conditional Execution `||` and `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
  - **[Variable Expansion in FOR Loops](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php)**
  - **[What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)**
  - **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: You don't need to escape the `&`- see my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your comment. This is for keep in one variable too.

Comment: @DavidPostill For to have the strings in variable and also get the value in clipboard

Comment: Also, I already knew the @barlop code