# Windows software to redirect console output to the cursor

Tags: windows, software-rec, console

It's not uncommon for me to have to run a command line program that gives me a unique code (kind of like an RSA SecurID token, but entirely software), and then paste that code into a web page or ssh session.

This is tedious.

So is there a program out there that I can assign a hotkey to run this command and simulate typing the result wherever the cursor is?

Bonus points for programs that...

- Entirely hide the console window so I never see it
- Allow me to define "normal" and "abnormal" results (via regex?) and will show a little popup for abnormal ones
- Are free

Edit: I'm on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Just and idea... What about automatically piping the output of your program to another program which would place it in the OS clipboard? Then you can just CTRL-V where you need it. This is discussed here: [How to pipe text from command line to the clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/97762/how-to-pipe-text-from-command-line-to-the-clipboard)

Comment: That's assuming he's not using Linux or Windows XP and earlier

Comment: That's not very helpful for SSH sessions where I'd still have to grab the mouse (Ctrl+V is piped through to the host).