# How to send rich text to the clipboard from command line?

Tags: html, clipboard

How can I send html to the clipboard as rich text from a script? My end goal is create a script so I can paste content from a source file into an email, but I want a general answer for pasting into any program that accepts rich text.

Example usage for pasting into email:

1. Open the source file in vim
2. Use `:TOhtml` command to create an html file with vim's syntax highlighting
3. Use an answer from here to copy the html as rich text
4. Paste into an email (this one wouldn't be scripted)

Related: [Pasting diff output into Microsoft Outlook with syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842313/79125)

Related: [Copy markdown input to the clipboard as rich text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84951/copy-markdown-input-to-the-clipboard-as-rich-text/84952#84952)

Comment: Related question on StackOverflow: [linux - getting HTML source or rich text from the X clipboard - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261379/getting-html-source-or-rich-text-from-the-x-clipboard), [windows - Accessing alternate clipboard formats from python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959928/accessing-alternate-clipboard-formats-from-python)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Linux

via [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84952)

```
cat text.html | xclip -t text/html
```

## Mac

via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6100348/79125)

```
cat text.html | textutil -stdin -format html -convert rtf -stdout | pbcopy
```

## Windows

In older Windows, you can natively only copy plaintext (via [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/97762/how-to-pipe-text-from-command-line-to-the-clipboard)).

```
type text.html | clip
```

In PowerShell you can copy rich text:

```
type text.html | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
```

If you create a C:\sandbox\pbcopy.ps1:

```
type $args[0] | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
```

Then you can [enable scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038991/79125) and then run it from anywhere (cmd.exe, .bat files, etc):

```
powershell C:\sandbox\pbcopy.ps1 text.html
```

There are [a few different Cygwin commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322594/cygwin-command-to-copy-to-windows-clipboard) to copy to Windows clipboard and it [looks like](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fxclip%2Fxclip-0.12-1) cygwin provides xclip, so you could probably use the Linux solution on Windows if you have cygwin.

Comment: With Windows you can put rich text to clipboard using cli. Just use following PowerShell command:
`Echo "<p>foo <strong>bar</strong></p>" | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml`

Comment: `-AsHtml` doesn't work for pasting to google docs (plain text appears), and there's no option `-AsRtf`. `xclip` requires X windows to be installed :-(

Answer (score 3):

## Also a Pandoc Solution

Developing on the answers here

### Alternative 1

- Use `:TOhtml`, this will give you a new buffer with the converted html. Next, use `:w ! xclip -t text/html -selection clipboard`
- When I pasted this in libreoffice, it had the line numbers. I tried disabling them, and repeating. This worked nicely.

### Solution using Pandoc:

- I prefer this, has a better formatting, and it is a one-liner

  `:w ! pandoc -s -t html | xclip -t text/html -selection clipboard`

### Some explaining:

- `:w ! {cmd}` will pipe the buffer to {cmd} in the shell command
- `pandoc -s -t html` will take the input and convert to html. I think you can omit the "-t html"
- "|" works as a pipe, since it's being interpreted as a shell command
- `xclip -t text/html -selection clipboard` is the answer given in the link [linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84952)

EDIT:
Trying to assign the command to a keybinding didn't work. It seems like the pipe is being used in the usual vim sense.

My workaround was to define a function:

```
function Html()
    let mytext = execute('w ! pandoc -s -t html | xclip -t text/html -selection clipboard')
    return mytext
endfunction
```

And then assigning a keybind to call this function:

```
nnoremap <leader>h :call Html()<cr>
```

Hope this helps. If anyone has a simpler solution, please comment!

Answer (score 2):

## Mac, for Google Docs

For Google Docs/Sheets running in Chrome on Mac, you can use [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/vi/ae5d1fe32ebcff0b618f931aee9a6067):

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

// Based on https://github.com/chbrown/macos-pasteboard/issues/8#issuecomment-906537204
import Cocoa
import Foundation

let pasteboard: NSPasteboard = .general

let dataTypeName : String = "public.html"
let dataType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: dataTypeName)
var text : String = ""
while let line = readLine() {
    text += line
    text += "\n"
}
let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
pasteboard.clearContents()
pasteboard.setData(data,  forType: dataType)
exit(0)
```

```
echo '<b>qwerty</b>' | ./pbcopy_html.swift
```

Note that it would paste *only* in Google Docs, pasting would fail in other places.

---

To extract html content from the clipboard, plain `pbpaste` can be used:

```
pbpaste -Prefer public.html
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use e-mail CSS! Use UTF8 encoding html file!

Run http (`HTML-eMail.html`) e-mail from comman line:

```
powershell .\mail-http.ps1
```

mail-http.ps1:

```
$time = get-date 

$from    = 'So.From@gmail.com'
$to      = 'So.To@gmail.com'
$subject = 'eMail-HTML ' + $time

$server=smtp.gmail.com;$port=587

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$email=new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $body)
$email.DeliveryNotificationOptions=[System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions]::Delay
$email.IsBodyHtml = $true
$email.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High

$email.BodyEncoding=$encoding

$email.Body = gc '.\HTML-eMail.html' -encoding UTF8

$smtp=new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($server,$port)
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Timeout = 30000  #ms
$smtp.Credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($from, 'derParol'); 

$smtp.Send($email)
```

HTML-eMail.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">

...

</html>
```

Comment: That only works if I want to compose an email in html. I may be replying to an existing email, I may want to paste into a word processor, etc. I've edited the question to clarify that email was an example, and not the real end goal.